# Advanced filter in excel including blank cells

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I have extracted and arranged the data from another database and now I would like to filter that data including the white cells.

So if I want to filter OP2048CN and then add another filter for the column "Calc Index" to be 1 then I would like that all the years (from 2021 to 2025) also shows up. Is there a way to do that only in exce? or would I need to use python?

[image]

Comment: When you 'arranged' the data from the database you removed the repetitive 'offer no' and 'calc index'. If you would have left them (so they are present in each row) the filtering would be straight forward filtering. So the question is why you removed this information from those rows. Most likely for presentation to humans'. You could then consider adding offerno and calcindex twice in your sheet. One like you have, one with all rows filled. Filter on the filled set and then either hide those columns, accept it or set print area or whatever

Comment: Three possible Excel methods: Add helper columns where the blanks are filled in; fill in the blanks on the main table but format them to be "invisible" (*i.e. font color same as interior color*); use `Power Query` (available in windows excel 2010+ and Office 365)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to select all your blank cells (`Go To Special...` -> `Blanks`) and fill-in them with the value that is stated above (type `=`, once press upper-arrow, hold on `Ctrl+Enter` or `Cmd+Enter`). You can find related MWE, e.g. [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/02/fill-blanks-excel/).